# Sequelize Op.and, Op.like resulting in empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a search endpoint with express and sequelize. When creating my 'where' object, all Op.and results in an empty object:

```
const where = {
        [Op.and]: req.query.q.split(" ").map((q) => {
            return { name: { [Op.like]: `%${q}%` } };
        }),
    };
console.log(where);
```

Resulting in the following output:

```
{}
```

Then I tried to omit the [Op.and]  part and changed it to the following

```
const where = req.query.q.split(" ").map((q) => {
    return { name: { [Op.like]: q } };
});
console.log(where);
```

Which outputs:

```
[
    {
        "name": {}
    },
    {
        "name": {}
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It's just the console.log that can't seem to handle it. My query doesn't work for some other strange but probably very logical reason.